# CSS floating attributes for facebook like

Tags: css, facebook-like

I'm only a beginner blogger and I don't know anything about CSS. Maybe someone can give me the correct css codes for a Facebook Like button.

Comment: Hi there. I see you asked many questions on StackOverflow but never accepted an answer. Please review the FAQ, *How do I ask questions here?* http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask

Comment: im so sorry about that and thank you for your reminder. don't know of that feature. anyway, thanks for the tip. found the answer by browsing stackexchange.

Answer (score 0):

[bam](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/) here it goes, just follow the steps on the left of the screen (scroll down a little). You don't need any css, unless you want to change its location or look.

Answer (score 0):

There are quite a few involved. For example: .button_count .like_button_dark .like_button_no_like .liketext, .button_count .connect_widget_like_button .liketext

Find a like button, right-click, and hit inspect element. You'll be able to see all css rules involved.